# use docker supervisor automatically run a script after start with a variable given in container start?

Tags: docker

So, I have different images which run different preconfigured cms systems, I have start scripts which map a given port to the exposed ports defined in the docker file.

My problem is now that I want a script to run after the container start. The script has to remote trigger a jenkins job which installs certain software bundles to the cms in my containers, therefore I need to pass the mapped ports to the jenkins job.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Is there a way of passing a variable given on the docker run command (in my case the -p settings) to a supervisor script or any other option that i can define in my dockerfile?

The basic idea here is to easily share prepared developer environments with workmates, so they don't have to install all the software themselves, but get a container with a readymade cms installation and just have to reinstall bundles they actually change without having to first install between 3 and 10 software bundles to actually see anything.

Comment: `-p` maps a port. You want `-e` for environment variables if you are looking for dynamic variables in Docker script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker start scripts, add an environment variable for your external port

```
-p $EXTPORT:$CMSPORT -e EXTPORT=$EXTPORT
```

Then the port will be available as `EXTPORT` in your containers environment.

```
$ docker run -e EXTPORT=4343 busybox sh -c 'echo $EXTPORT'
4343
```